# Xpages: Type ahead styling is all screwed up with Mobile theme

Tags: css, mobile, xpages, typeahead

I have a mobile app I'm building that has a simple field type-ahead.

```
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"
                value="#{contact.AlwaysAccess}">
                <xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="1">
                    <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[one
two
three
four
five
six]]></xp:this.valueList>
                </xp:typeAhead>
            </xp:inputText>
```

I have applied the following theme and rules to the db so that any xpage starting with a prefix of m gets rendered for mobile.

```
    xsp.ajax.renderwholetree=false
    xsp.error.page.default=true
    xsp.html.doctype=HTML\ PUBLIC\ "-//W3C//DTD\ HTML\ 4.01//EN"\     "http\://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library
    xsp.persistence.mode=file
    xsp.resources.aggregate=true
    xsp.theme=oneuiv2.1
    xsp.theme.mobile.pagePrefix=m
    xsp.theme.mobile.android=iphone
```

As soon as I specify that the xpage is a mobile xpage the formating of the type ahead fields get screwed up.

I check it out on the mobile sample app and the same thing happened. has any one else found this? And what is the simplest way to fix it short of ditching themes and starting styling from scratch?
Any Ideas?

Comment: I've seen this behavior too. I was going to suggest using a Dojo filtering select instead of a standard input text with typeahead... but apparently that's exactly what an input with typeahead is, because the resulting markup is styled identically.

Comment: Paul Withers has a blog post on the topic: http://www.intec.co.uk/xpages-mobile-controls-and-value-pickers-part-two-client-side-approach/

Comment: Thanks Guys. Paul I had a look at the article you posted very interesting. I was hoping not to leave the page as the ipad has plenty of realestate but I think this might be a good option. Thanks

Comment: Are the relevant styles pushed down to mobile? It's possible that mobile default CSS suppresses whatever's necessary. I'd recommend using Safari or Firefox to switch user agent and check the styling, cross-referencing with the non-mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Ajax Type Ahead on XPages mobile apps (LAMY8ZVRG2) which we're looking to address post Domino 9.0.
The workaround is to include the styling for the type ahead from the tundra.css  like so...

```
  <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet
        href="/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.0-u/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    </xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Or better still is to copy the styling from tundra.css that applies only to Type Ahead control

**But** this is very risky at the moment, since it might break the visual appearance of some dojo form controls on mobile.
 So the advice is not to use this workaround unless it doesn't effect the display of other controls and UI on your XPages mobile app.

Comment: Thanks Paul I tried adding the style sheet it still kept the little boxes and rendered the type ahead more like a bullet style list. So I've removed the m prefix from the xpage. Still sits inside a single page layout, but I'm manually styling it. Type ahead working so thats the important thing. Thanks for your suggestion. Mel

Answer (score 0):

I had severe problems with typeahead for a mobile application that I developed. In the end, I gave up using Ext.lib and Dojo. I disabled Dojo for the mobile XPages and replaced it with jQuery Mobile. Although it took some time to recode the application it turned out to be worthwile. The "app" ended up running much better - and styling was simpler than with the XPages/Dojo setup. And the controls behaved as expected. In short I moved from trial-and-error to I-am-in-control :-)

Just to give you a quick idea of how to include jQuery Mobile instead of Dojo, I use a custom control with the following code:

```
    <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="/xpUtil.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    <xp:linkResource rel="apple-touch-icon">
        <xp:this.href><![CDATA[${javascript:getDbPath() + "mobileHomeLogo.png"}]]></xp:this.href>
    </xp:linkResource>
    <xp:script src="/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:script src="/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:metaData name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"></xp:metaData>
    <xp:metaData name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"></xp:metaData>
    <xp:styleSheet href="/km2012j.css"></xp:styleSheet>
    <xp:script src="/local.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:facesContext.getRequestParameters().setJsLibrary(0);}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

As you can see the code also includes some of my own JS-libraries. But you get the idea....

It may not be a viable solution for you, however, it may be worthwile having a look at.

/John

Comment: Thank John, the thought crossed my mind but there are too many features and controls that are just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should make the typeahead readable on a mobile device...

```
.dijitReset.dijitValidationContainer {
  display:none;
}
.dijitComboBoxMenuPopup {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```